# Two Function execute in the same time

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have an app that is connected with bluetooth to two devices. From these devices I rescue some data and save them in the DB.

Basically what I do is:

*Search Device 1 & Connect*, inside this function I launch *Search Device 2*

*Search Device 2 & Connect*, inside this function I launch first a function to recover the service(the data that I need to recover form the external Device) from device1 and then from device2.

In this way when I recover the data, there is a delay from the two devices. So the first device connected send data first than the second device.

In your opinion, how can I optimize this code, so that there is not this difference between the data collected by the two devices?

This is my code:

```
    scan1() { // scan to find the first device. 
    this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
          if (error) {
            return;
          }
    this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
    device
              .connect()
              .then(() => {
               // launch function to find the second device. 
                this.scan2();
    }

// Function to find the second device. 
    scan2() {
    this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
    if (error) {
            return;
          }
     this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
      device
              .connect()
              .then(() => {
                console.log("--Connected.--");
                console.log(" ");
              })
              .then(() => {
                // function to find services from device1
                this.deviceService1(this.state.deviceName1);
                // function to find services from device2
                this.deviceService2(this.state.deviceName2);
              })

    deviceService1(device) {
        console.log("device.name: " + device.name)
            device
            .discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics()
            .then(() => {
              console.log("(this.setupNotifications1") // This is the function about the type of data that I need to recover
              this.setupNotifications1(device);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              this.error(error.message);
            });
        }
      }

      deviceService2(device) {
        console.log("device.name: " + device.name)
             device
            .discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics()
            .then(() => {
              console.log("(this.setupNotifications2") // This is the function about the type of data that I need to recover
              this.setupNotifications2(device);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              this.error(error.message);
            });
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you find yourself using numbers as suffixes for method names, that's a good indicator you can iterate instead. While it's not always bad to repeat yourself, your code was redundant. 
Also, by stopping the scan immediately for each device, there's a good chance that the first device would simply be scanned and connected twice.

The `startDeviceScan` callback is called [once per device.](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx/wiki/Bluetooth-Scanning) So we just need to call it once, wait until two devices connect, *then* stop scanning.

`Promise.all` takes an array of promises, allowing us to simultaneously set up both devices, thus removing the delay from the user's experience.

You'll notice I use `async/await` quite a bit. This is simply a matter of style and habit. This code could also be implemented without it.

```
async scanDevices() {
    const bothDevices = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Timeout failsafe if devices never connect
        setTimeout(
            () => reject(new Error('Device scan timed out')),
            10000 /* 10 seconds */
        );
        const devices = [];
        this.manager.startDeviceScan(
            null,
            null,
            /* Listener Called For Every Device */
            async (error, device) => {
                // exit on error
                if (error) return console.error(error);
                try {
                    // exit callback if already connected 
                    if (await device.isConnected()) return;
                    // connect
                    await device.connect();
                    console.log(`DEVICE: ${device.name} - CONNECTED`);
                    devices.push(device);
                    // Only scan 2 devices
                    if (devices.length >= 2) {
                        this.manager.stopDeviceScan();
                        // resolves promise, setting `bothDevices` 
                        resolve(devices);
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error(e);
                }
            }
        );
    });
    // Setup both at the same time
    await Promise.all(bothDevices.map(device => this.setupDevice(device)));
}

async setupDevice(device) {
    try {
        await device.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics();
        this.setupNotifications(device);
    } catch (e) {
        this.error(e.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh fantastic :) Just one question! When I launch this.setupNotifications(device), this function is for the two devices? If Yes how can I distinguish the right device from the left that is read with this function?

Comment: Yes! I added that as a challenge. The devices have [ID's and names](https://polidea.github.io/react-native-ble-plx/#device) to distinguish them. If connection order is the determining factor for left/right, you could save the id's respectively before calling the setup function. e.g. `this.deviceIds = { leftId: devices[0].id, rightId: devices[1].id }`, then check `if(device.id == this.deviceIds.rightId)` or vice versa in your `setupNotifications` function

Comment: @So I save the id like:     
this.deviceId1 = {device1: devices[0].id, device2: devices[1].id} and then I should pass it await Promise.all(bothDevices.map(device => this.setupDevice(device))); (how?)

Comment: You don't have to pass it as an argument because you saved it to the instance. (`this`) You can access `this.deviceIds` from any method in that instance. So you can access it in `this.setupNotifications(` using `this.deviceIds`

Comment: Then you're passing the `device` as an argument all the way through. So you can compare `device.id` against the saved id's in `this.deviceIds`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I'm trying your code but I receive this kind of error: 
ExceptionsManager.js:82 BleError: Device ? is already connected
ExceptionsManager.js:82 BleError: Operation was cancelled

Comment: You're welcome! It sounds like you need to check if the device is already connected before invoking the `#connect()` method. I updated the code above to exit if the device has already connected. (using the `Device#isConnected()` method)

Comment: I receive the same error :( I have tried to print const devices = [] and there aren't devices

Comment: After a little digging, it would seem that this library (contradictory to hardware & operating system capabilities) only allows you to connect to one device at once. This seems to be a common error (https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx/issues/198, https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx/issues/271)

Comment: If you want to connect to multiple devices, it would seem that you can’t use the react-native-ble-plx / RxBluetoothKit / RxAndroidBle libraries

Answer (score 3):

Because promises are async, you'll have to nest the second function my friend or: you can have an async function wrap the calls to both and use 'await'. Not sure how else to approach this.

Comment: Oooh that's the problem! Thank you for your answer :) How can I nest the second function??

Comment: return the promise from the sub calls, (scan1 and scan2),

async function both() {
     await scan1() // inside of scan1, await scan 2
}

Comment: @Ale8k you're on the right track, but the `both` function would only abstract the same problem into `async/await` syntax. `scan2` still has to wait for `scan1` to finish. Using `Promise.all`, both scans can run simultaneously. But there are also intrinsic problems with the original scanning process. These issues are addressed in my answer

Comment: Ahhh I get you, I'm mostly using RxJS so apologies if my Promises are rusty :P